# How do I read the OEM Information from Windows using C#?

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, compact-framework

I am using windows mobile device 6 with compact framework c# .

I need to get the following data :

1. OEM Name
2. OEM Version

How to acheive this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no standard for this information and no API.

Look thru the registry for HKLM\Platform or other location with the information you need.